# fncychap style not being used

Tags: fncychap

I want to change the display style of chapters in my document. I use the `fncychap` package. Here are the settings :

```
\usepackage[glenn]{fncychap} % Pour changer les chapitres
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sf}
\ChNumVar{\Huge}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Large\rm}
\ChRuleWidth{1pt}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase
```

When I run my code, the style doesn't change. I didn't find anything here or on internet about this issue. Here is my preamble :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn,twoside]{book}
% Format + encodage
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

% ----------------------------------------
% Package pour la conception d'un document
% ----------------------------------------
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage[obeyFinal]{easy-todo}
%\usepackage[obeyDraft]{todonotes} % Pour des boites dans la marge
% ----------------------------
% Packages pour la mise en page
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} % Mise en page type livre
\usepackage{setspace} % \singlespacing ; \onehalfspacing ; \doublespacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{changepage} % Pour adjustwidth
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
% modification des titres
%\usepackage{titlesec} % Pour changer l'apparence des titres
% =======================================================
\usepackage[glenn]{fncychap} % Pour changer les chapitres
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sf}
\ChNumVar{\Huge}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Large\rm}
\ChRuleWidth{1pt}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase
% -------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontawesome} % Pour rajouter des symboles
\usepackage{lettrine} % Pour avoir des lettrines
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Pour changer la couleur des titres
% ----------------------------
% Packages pour le mode math
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[g]{esvect}
% ----------------------------
% Packages pour le dessin
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{fancybox}
% libraries Tikz
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
% ---------------------------------
% En-tête et pied de page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\emph{Les petits carnets de l'ingénieur}}
\fancyhead[R]{Nicolas \textsc{Lesquoy}}
%\renewcommand\footrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Page \thepage}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\today}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textsc{ISAE-Supaero}}
% ----------------------------
% Packages pour le choix de la police
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{addfont} % Pour les lettres cursives très jolies
\addfont{OT1}{rsfs10}{\rsfs}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{calligra}
% ----------------------------
% Packages pour présenter du code
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{pprint}{
language=Python,
breaklines=true,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray!40},
stringstyle=\color{violet},
numberstyle=\tiny,
keepspaces=true,
numbers=left,
%frame=single,
%framesep=2pt,
aboveskip=1ex,
showtabs=true,
captionpos=b
} % Python

\lstset{literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1
  {°}{{\degres}}1
} % Problème d'encodage
```

The document is composed of differents `.tex` files which are included in my `main.tex` file with `\input{file}`.
Could someone help me solving this issue ?

Comment: Load `sectsty` before `fncychap`. But think twice before using the latter package, which produce very dubious results from a typographical point of view.

Comment: Thanks, it worked in a certain manner but the defined style isn't used correctly. I only have the font selected and not the lines that should be drawn, and that is true for any style I choose.

Comment: The package option is `Glenn`, not `glenn`. And it produces one of the worst chapter heading I have ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `sectsty` before `fncychap` and to use the correct package option:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
```

I mean, if you ***really*** want to get this peculiar chapter heading style.

[image]

Comment: I personnaly like the look of it, thank you for taking the time to help me.